# How Do I Select an Object by Embedded Object Value 2 Levels Deep in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have an object that has an embedded list of objects, which itself has an embedded list of object, like so

```
namespace AppName.Models
{
    [BindProperties]
public class WorkOrder
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int FinishedGoodsToMake { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public List<FinishedGood> FinishedGoods { get; set; } = new List<FinishedGood>();
}

[BindProperties]
public class FinishedGood
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public List<RawMaterial> RawMaterials{ get; set; } = new List<RawMaterial>();
}

[BindProperties]
public class RawMaterial
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
}
```

In the RawMaterial object, the Status can have a value of 0, 1, 2 or 3. I need to process them grouped by this status. I think it would be easiest if I could just loop through statuses and select the object I need. So, let's say the work order has three FinishedGoods and each FinishedGood has four RawMaterials. I need to get a full WorkOrder object, with FinishedGoods and RawMaterials, only where RawMaterial.Status == 0. Is there any way to do this easily?

I could optionally map the object to iterate through each status also. Just looking for the easiest/ most elegant solution here. Thanks!

Comment: `var by_status = work_order.FinishedGoods.SelectMany(g => g.RawMaterials).ToLookup(m => m.Status)`?

Comment: Thanks @GSerg - this gives me an ILookup of the status. Not sure if I can get what I need from there. I'll see if I can find more info on ILookup.

Comment: `foreach (var m in by_status[0]) { }`?

Comment: Ok, so that gives me the raw material, but it doesn't give me the associated FinishedGood or WorkOrder